# How to test my Kubernetes Architecture (With drone.io)

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, drone.io

I'm currently working on a kubernetes project, and I want to put my work in prod, but before that,  the company wants to be able to test the kubernetes architecture (create the right pod, communicate, etc... ).

About the architecture :
   -It's a single NODE architecture powered by minikube
   - I've got some POD, some JOB, 1 cronJob 
   - My jobs are managed by a python script who call the API

I need to be able to test my architecture and my python script (with pytest)
As a CD/CI, the company use Drone.io
I already try kind, pupernetes, and ding.

Any idea?

PS: It's my first post on StackOverflow so if I made any mistake just tell me

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate your version control with drone.io ( i assume you already have)

```
Configure drone.io to make docker images of you code/app

Push docker images to registry

Configure a webhook that fires a deployment upon getting the new tag for image

Configure the kubernetes yaml manifest for deploymenet that will be deployed to kuberntes

Refine that above steps so that it works for test/dev/prod environmenets.
```

Ideally you commit code to test/dev , package it as docker image , test it in test namespace , and then port the change to prod branch , followed by new docker build , and kubernetes deployment

Comment: First thanks for your fast answer, i'm going to try it and come back to you soon

Comment: I'm new to drone.io so excuse me if my question seems dumb
What my docker image will contain ( the one make by drone.io)